Could a cold hycean planet form in a system with terrestrial planets and gas giants?
This is a star system populated with terrestrial planets on the inside and gas giants past the frostline, like in our solar system. Call it a "classical solar system" if you will. My question is:
Is there a realistically probable chance that a hycean planet could form at the far reaches (relative distance to Neptune) of the system? I am aware that if a hycean planet were to form here, it would fall into the category of 'cold hycean planets' due to its distance from the parent star.

"Is there a chance...." is a very poor wording for a question. Given enough time, there is a chance that a bottle of perfume will be filled by the scented room. So, there is chance that anything, no matter how unlikely, happens, just give it enough time. What is your real problem?

I wouldnt worry too much if a specific planet could have formed in a specific position in a one-off star system. Even if it could not, there is alway the chance is has migrated there or even captured from outside the system.

Note that weightier gases (methane, nitrogene, co2) would be pretty fine between the hidrogen and liquid water layers and odds are that they would collect exactly there.

Given that we're pretty sure both Uranus and Neptune have liquid water, and a hydrogen heavy atmosphere, all that really separates them from true hycean worlds like K2-18b is the relative size of their rocky components. So the question really becomes whether there could be enough rocky material at that range from the star to form a rockier world? That's a question with a definite answer, yes there could, but for which we have no particular evidence concerning the likelihood having not yet directly observed planetary formation in detail.
